# How to minimize churn in visual studio designer files

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, diff

In Visual Studio, the Designer View reads and generates the `*.Designer.cs` for whatever form you're working on. As a result it's an active generated file (as opposed to passive ones such as build outputs). In the case of VCS's like Git these generated files are diffed in plain text which isn't a good way to compare changes (or in this case merge conflicts).
Question: Are there any solutions to minimizing the amount of needless churn created by auto-generated files?
Thoughts I've had so far:

- Treat them as binary files (just overwrite what's going out)
- Try to "game the system" and figure out what makes the code generate generate things in a specific order
- Find/make a tool that compares the differences between the two files (e.g. something that would highlight the differences between 2 .pngs, but for .Designer.cs files)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this.  Those files are nice, readable C#.  They diff nicely (if you make a change, you can read the diff and see what the change was).  In the case of a merge, you can read the code and understand what should and should not end up in the merged result.  Why do you think _"diffed in plaintext which isn't a good way to compare changes "_ for these files?

Comment: It's become a bit of a hassle because we removed some items then tried to rebase another load of changes on top of the file and nearly all of them had conflicts between removing the files and nothing.

Comment: It may work to manually rearrange parts of the Designer code, to minimize differences and conflicts between versions. But you may also find yourself repeatedly having to do that. These files were not really meant for average human eyes to see, also they were invented long before text diffing was as common as it is now, and the tooling is in no way optimized for it.

Comment: WinForms designers (in different VS releases) do not generate stable code, which can be quite hard to diff/merge, so treating such generated files as binary can save you tons of time. The diff is in general meaningless.

Comment: Thanks @everyone. I'm also investigating into VS's git tools (maybe they adapted for this kind of stuff) as well as our use of SourceTree/Bitbucket (maybe it's an tool specific thing).